# Persisting application settings with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

What is the best/prettiest/most flexible way of storing application settings with Hibernate?

Is a single row table the way to go, or is there a better way? The ability to store extra settings in the same place/table, but outside of the application domain would be nice.

I've experimented with a Key/Value table, for example:

```
Key      | Value
-------------------------
width    | 20px
height   | 40px
showall  | true
etc.
```

But this doesn't seem to fit Hibernate very well.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there really a need to store these in a SQL database? Will you ever be joining this data against other data, querying it from other apps, etc? Or is it just the most convenient place to store it?

Comment: In most cases, I'd say no. But in this case, I'm working with two different applications (on different machines) that are both working against the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually implemented this as a key/value pair in C# with nHibernate.  The table is the same as you described with just a key/value pairing.  When I want to get/set a value my persistence layer accepts the "key" (as an enumeration) and returns a ApplicationSetting object.  This object is really just a wrapper for the key/value pair.

Simple Example (in c#):

```
class ApplicationSetting
{
  private string theApplicationSettingString = string.Empty;

  /// <summary>
  /// The name of the setting.
  /// </summary>
  public virtual ApplicationSettingKey SettingName
  {
     //I use enumerations here so that I'm guaranteed to get a key I
     //already know about and not a random string.
     get
     {
        return (ApplicationSettingKey)Enum.Parse(
           typeof(ApplicationSettingKey), theApplicationSettingString);
     }
     set
     {
        theApplicationSettingString =
           Enum.GetName(typeof(ApplicationSettingKey), value);
     }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The value of the setting.
  /// </summary>
  public virtual string SettingValue
  {
     get;
     set;
  }
}



/// <summary>
/// Enumeration for all application settings.
/// </summary>
public enum ApplicationSettingKey
{
     WIDTH,
     HEIGHT,
     SHOWALL
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns the ApplicationSetting from the database that corresponds to 
/// the passed in key/name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aKey">The key/name of the Application setting to 
/// retrieve.</param>
/// <returns>The ApplicationSetting Definition that with the corresponding
/// application setting key/name.</returns>
public ApplicationSetting GetApplicationSettingByKey(ApplicationSettingKey aKey)
{
    const string propertyName = "theApplicationSettingString";
    string key = Enum.GetName(typeof(ApplicationSettingKey), aKey);
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ApplicationSetting>();
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(propertyName, key));
    return FindFirst(criteria);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this approach, but I'd recommend anyone reading this to evaluate all the other proposed solutions before here as well as any other existing technique, before making a decision.

Comment: @Kristoffer I completely agree that others should look at all the solutions.  This solution was chosen for my project because it fit well with other parts of the project.

Comment: saving any type as a string is error-prone approach. It's better to use ability of ORM to map types properly. So I suggest to create separate columns with proper types for each settings key. And obviously you should prevent creation of multiple settings rows.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you organize your domain model based on how the values are used (similar to how you would organize any OO model), and then persist those entities. For your example, you would have a `Window` object with `width`, `height`, and `showall` attributes, which you then persist to the database as a single row/object.

This way you could have the following (hypothetical situation):

```
id | layoutType | width | height | images
-----------------------------------------------
0  | widescreen | 1000  | 500    | true
1  | normal     | 600   | 500    | true
2  | mobile     | 320   | 480    | false
```

Answer (score 2):

To strictly answer your question, you *can* map a key/value table with Hibernate:

```
@Entity
public class Settings {
    @Id
    private String key;
    private String value;

    // getters, setters, etc
}
```

But whether you really need to store this in a database or not, I think I'd go for [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) instead of Hibernate (or maybe <strike>just a `Properties` object if you don't need the settings to be persited in a database</strike> the [`Preferences`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API as suggested by @ring).

Comment: Rather, `java.util.Preferences` based APIs